# Redis streams - free struck messages in a consumer group without claiming

Tags: .net-core, redis, redis-streams

Lets say, there are messages in a Redis consumer group that has not been processed for N seconds. I am trying to understand if its possible to free them and put them back for other members of the consumer group to see it. I don't want to claim/process these struck messages. I just want to make them accessible to other active members of the consumer group. Is this possible?

From what I have understood from the documents, options mentioned are XAUTOCLAIM or use a combination of XPENDING and XCLAIM and neither of these are meeting my requirements.

Essentially, I am trying to create a standalone process that can act as monitor and make those messages visible to active consumers in the consumer group and I am planning to use this standalone process to perform similar activity for multiple consumer groups (around 30). So I don't want this standalone process to be taking other actions.

Please suggest how this can be designed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Pending messages are removed from the Redis' PEL only when they are acknowledged**: this is by design and allows to scale the message re-distribution process to each individual consumer and to avoid the single point of failure condition of having a single monitoring process like the one you described.

So, in short, what you are looking for can't be done and I would suggest to consider using `XAUTOCLAIM` or `XPENDING` / `XCLAIM` into your consumer processes instead.